# What does Bjarne Stroustrup mean with "foundation libraries" in his FAQ?

Tags: c++

I'm reading [Bjarne Stroustrup's FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html). In the section: [*What C++ compiler do you recommend? Which libraries?*](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#recommend), he says:

> Also, where possible, prefer the standard library to **non-standard "foundation libraries"** and try to minimize use of proprietary extensions.

What does this bolded part mean? What are *foundation libraries*?

Comment: my first guess is that he refers to libs like qt, they are well established, have a huge community, but still if possible you should prefer standard c++

Comment: same link, sligthly different context "...library so that the users of that subset must invent their own incompatible foundation libraries" I think he does not use it as part of a strict terminology, but rather to refer to libraries in a general sense. I am voting to close as opionion-based, btw, because only BS can know what he really meant and after quick research I think there is no definite answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around it's quite clear, that *foundation library* means a library, which defines a standard programming environment for a platform. There used to be many of these, from IBM, Borland, Microsoft, Sun, etc. Usually, they provide ways of interacting with the operating system, with graphics, databases, containers, and occasionally some algorithms.